# guzzle 6 500 Internal Server Error BadMethodCallException laravel php

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

i'm trying to make request with guzzle. i have two condition when data has token then go on if or else. else part is working when send like but how can pass header like that it shows internal server error

$data is like this:

```
Array ( [userId] => 87 [token] => eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImI2ZGE3ZTM4ODYyYWU5NzQwNWNlZDcxYTQ3YzIzNTY4ZGU1MzU4ODA4YmI4YjUzZDJlNGI1YTE1ZGQ0NjMyZWRjYzc0ZTllNmZiZGQ1MGI0In0.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiYjZkYTdlMzg4NjJhZTk3NDA1Y2VkNzFhNDdjMjM1NjhkZTUzNTg4MDhiYjhiNTNkMmU0YjVhMTVkZDQ2MzJlZGNjNzRlOWU2ZmJkZDUwYjQiLCJpYXQiOjE1ODcxMDI3NDIsIm5iZiI6MTU4NzEwMjc0MiwiZXhwIjoxNjE4NjM4NzQyLCJzdWIiOiI4NyIsInNjb3BlcyI6W119.WwtepUSktopeikIL-7n3BfZYLO0_rhLSfT13yt1jo8xJp5xZBh2_WVexy8ifXx2oTgVX3n2JB-I3aAMYVbeJP-6SHsyF81LqvOQDYm-Jx9YBI4ihksbF1tDx8mjtmFUTnLAJBn1V451oUVtomAFaQ4xIQxn7AFaxVPF_MY_dziPf4dWSSehq9pP6IAn7yXGlRiBdnpmsca_m03FcLlGwpLc3tGh7qIEjg726kFecvzy7xDyUtJ1CPy0N-bErMDg_Cdvaidbqg5oJoBL8Zuw8Ec1k9DrKAxtGqAuo2OwMjoQlXcavuga_-Mwrh4MKdoH6WyXSOlHze4H_o0w2g7JtRVG4lrUz6NuA0Ys1DlAIZd5V1E44eNFfu849Magtfaun4AbOAQpHKNtF3G9efkcT0OVHsl3qct3OvjNzFWOALDV8Cops_rsVWz1goWbkz0gvJas8eGq0V7qPIdo-ZdHt7RX-GJWILvC9B9uUgWr3GGNQqIAPMzIV4i6VMd0v_VggJk9pDCGMyhLP2fw6SOGFYi33U0IkNApEPCeqixpAAybZlJbt8EnfS1XXKyjDRZH2W-PfJyO_cSoO4gaXLJktoL0ew5uVRvda-UcQnl2dPTPNQbcPG3S0_ADyyMJdsgJDlDebTikuRSOwENpwFBmDJAYTMT9Zu3Y8hDwARsK5vJI [language] => en )
```

​

```
    if (isset($data['token'])){

    $headers = [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$data['token'],
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    ];


    $response = $client->request($requestType,$url,
    [
       'json' => [
           'header' => $headers,
           'data' => $data
       ]
]);

}
else{
   $headers = [
       'content-type' => 'application/json'
   ];
    $response = $client->request($requestType,$url,
    [
        'json'   => $data

]);
}

$contents = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);           
return $contents;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it

```
$response = $client->request($requestType,$url,
    [
       'json' => $data,
       'headers' => $headers,
]);
```

Comment: so i needed to pass headers separately